# hello i have this proplem chmod: missing operand after ‘+x’

Tags: chmod

hello every body im new in linux so i have this proplem im writing this coomand '' chmod +x'' in ubuntu but when i click enter it shows chmod: chmod: missing operand after ‘+x’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Sounds like you're missing a file name. Could you [edit] your question to include the full command? This will make it easier to confirm 

Comment: You haven't told us what you want to achieve. It sounds as if you have downloaded a script from Internet, or created one, and are trying to run it on your system. Was the `chmod +x` command part of the instructions for the script? Then it should be followed by the filename of the script, as @Mahmoud answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You should specify a file or directory

`chmod +x script.sh`
will give execution permission to `script.sh` file

Comment: okay what should i do now

Comment: yeah it works thanks